# Linebreaking of links

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, tabulator

I have a column filled with text in tabulator. The text is displayed with line breaks.

```
{title:"Title", field:"title", formatter:"textarea"},
```

[image]

When I introduce the [built in URL formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/format#format-builtin), the text in the first column does not break anymore.

```
  {title:"Title", field:"title", formatter:"textarea", formatter:"link", formatterParams:{target:"_blank", urlField:"source"}},
```

[image]

Is there a way to introduce link while keeping the linebreaks?

Comment: I don't understand your question, the code you provided is a string or it's to code in itself? If it's a code then what language is it? If it's string, can you provide a larger example?

Comment: http://tabulator.info/examples/4.5 I will try to rephrase

Comment: I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: What happens if you use:  {title:"Title", field:"title", formatter:"textarea", formatterParams:{target:"_blank", urlField:"source"}}

Comment: Then the table does not load. And if I remove the `formatter:"link"` the link is gone.

Comment: It would be helpful if you created a **[mcve]**.  Just shove some example data into some example code that causes the problem.

Comment: could you add an overflow-wrap to the css? That may help..

Answer (score 3):

By default, tabulator renders the cells with "white-space: nowrap" (as defined in CSS class *tabulator-cell* in *tabulator.css*).

The formatter "textarea" overrides that by manually setting "pre-wrap" on the style of the cell element: [modules/format.js](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/f9bad23f57c5bcad50ae8fc8f6f625e3f1525447/dist/js/modules/format.js#L134)

**Options:**

1. Write a [custom formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/format#format-custom) (to render a link with "white-space: pre-wrap")
2. Add your own CSS (*after* *tabulator.css*, to make sure the css cascade works) to target links inside *tabulator-cell* to set "white-space: pre-wrap". This should work:

   ```
   .tabulator-row .tabulator-cell a {
       white-space: pre-wrap;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the code of 2 within `<style></style>` behind `<link href="tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` but it does not linebreak the links.

Comment: My bad. It's "-" instead of "_" in the CSS. Let me update this

Comment: Here's a working example on JSBin: https://jsbin.com/fudinedowu/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

> http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/format#format-height
>
> ## Variable Height Formatters
>
> By default formatters will keep their contents within the height of the current row, hiding any overflow.
>   The only exception to this is the **textarea** formatter which will
>   automatically vary its height when the column is resized so its
>   contents does not overflow.
>
> If you would like this functionally to appear in another type of
>   formatter you can set the **variableHeight** property to **true** in the
>   column definition and it will will behave in a similar way to the
>   textarea formatter:
>
> `{title:"Name", field:"name", formatter:myCustomFormatter, variableHeight:true}`

also you can not set multiple formatters at once , that is wrong:

```
{title:"Title", field:"title", formatter:"textarea", formatter:"link", formatterParams:{target:"_blank", urlField:"source"}}
-                              ^^^^^^^^^ overriden by ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! When I remove `formatter:"textarea"` and introduce `variableHeight:true` there is still no line breaking.