# Tabulator - how to create multi-line text in formatter:"link"

Tags: tabulator

I use http://tabulator.info and want to have a html link in the table cell. I use `formatter:"link"` and everything works:

```
{title:"Reference", field:"ref", headerSort:false, formatter:"link",  variableHeight:true, formatterParams:{labelField:"name", target:"_blank", urlField:"link",  urlPrefix:"articles/"}, width:"185"},
```

But the text from `labelField` is not multi-line, such as possible with `formatter:"textarea"`. Is it possible to have multi-line text of the html link?

Thanks, Vadim

Answer (score 3):

many thanks for the answer, but it seems like I am not so strong to do this with Custom Formaters... So I found this: [Linebreaking of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215573/linebreaking-of-links) and that:

```
 .tabulator-row .tabulator-cell a {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
```

works. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using [Custom Formaters](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/format#format-builtin) for creating multi-line rows. The gist is that the custom formater gets called as the data enters the table, with the cell being passed as a param. You can pull the cell data out of that (`cell.getValue()`) and manipulate it as you need. At least that is what I am doing to add `Font Awesome` icons to various rows based on the data contained. I use `Handlebars` to format an `HTML` snippet and return that when the custom formater function is called

Anyway, not sure I understand what you are needing to do but maybe this will help.

---

```
let eventTableItemMediaScript = `
<div>{{eventTitle}}</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between mr-1">
<small>
{{eventDate}}
</small>
<i class="{{iconName}}" style="color:{{iconColor}}"></i>
</div>
`
let eventTableItemMediaTemplate = Handlebars.compile(eventTableItemMediaScript);
```

[image]

---

**From the docs**

```
{title:"Name", field:"name", formatter:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
    //cell - the cell component
    //formatterParams - parameters set for the column
    //onRendered - function to call when the formatter has been rendered

    return "Mr" + cell.getValue(); //return the contents of the cell;
    },
}
```